# data entering in a reqiured manner in ms excel

Tags: excel

I want the data to be filled in ms excel cells as shown below

d0-d7  #this entry should be in first cell, if i drag vertically downwards, automatically it should

d8-d15

d16-d23

d24-d31

d32-d39  something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Type number 7 in cell `A1` and number 15 in cell `A2`, drag it as much as you require.

[image]

In column `B1` paste below formula and drag. The below formula is the `CONCATENATE` of `d` and numbers as per your requiremnt.

```
=CONCATENATE("d",A1-$A$1,"-","d",A1)
```